# How to get the window width in blazor

Tags: blazor

I'm trying gu get the window width for responsive stuff.
Thanks!

I have tryied 
`@code{ public WindowState State { get; set; } = WindowState.Default;}`

```
`@code{private Window myWindow = ?}`
```

Comment: use [JS interopt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to do that

Comment: You might want to look for a nuget package called BlazorSize by Ed Charbeneau

Comment: The only part where I use JS Interop on [Blagario](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/Blagario/blob/master/src/blagario/Pages/_Host.cshtml#L21)

Comment: Do we have to use JS to do this?  Surely blazor its self has this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 12):

Check this link for a tutorial
https://blazor.tips/blazor-how-to-ready-window-dimensions/

basically you need to register the IJSRuntime to invoke a JS `getDimensions()` function

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class BrowserService
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _js;

    public BrowserService(IJSRuntime js)
    {
        _js = js;
    }

    public async Task<BrowserDimension> GetDimensions()
    {
        return await _js.InvokeAsync<BrowserDimension>("getDimensions");
    }

}

public class BrowserDimension
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

JS Details

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.getDimensions = function() {
        return {
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: If the JavaScript function, getDimensions, is not available because you have navigated to another Blazor page (in Blazor WASM), then put your JavaScript function in a separate file, e.g. getDimensions.js, and dynamically load it, e.g.
public async Task<BrowserDimension> GetDimensions()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "getDimensions.js");
        return await _js.InvokeAsync<BrowserDimension>("getDimensions");
    }

Answer (score 2):

Create a JavaScript file, e.g. scripts/getwindowsize.js:

```
export function getWindowSize()
{
    return {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    };
};
```

In your .razor file:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

Displaly the Window size: @windowWidth, @windowHeight
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnButtonClick">Get Dimensions</button>

@code {
    private IJSObjectReference jsModule;

    public int windowHeight, windowWidth;

    public class WindowDimensions
    {
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            jsModule = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/getwindowsize.js");
        }
    }

    private async Task OnButtonClick()
    {
        var dimension = await jsModule.InvokeAsync<WindowDimensions>("getWindowSize");
        windowHeight = dimension.Height;
        windowWidth = dimension.Width;
    }

}
```

Don't forget to tell you browser to do a hard reload, and empty the cache, if you changed the contents of getwindowsize.js, such as if you used an answer from a previous answer or web site.

This is for Blazor WebAssembly, .Net Core 5.

Answer (score 0):

@Nerdroid:s example does not work when window is resized, this is how I tuned it to work with resize as well.

Here is service that can be used in components

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace SecretAppBlazor.Data

{
    public class BrowserService
    {
        private readonly IJSRuntime _js;
        BrowserDimension _browserDimension;
        public event Action<BrowserDimension> DimensionsChanged;

    public BrowserService(IJSRuntime js)
    {
        _js = js;
    }

    public async Task<BrowserDimension> GetDimensions()
    {
        _browserDimension = await _js.InvokeAsync<BrowserDimension>("getDimensions");
        return _browserDimension;
    }

    public async Task RegisterResizeListener()
    {
        await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.registerViewportChangeCallback", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void OnResize(int width, int height)
    {
        if (_browserDimension.Width == width && _browserDimension.Height == height) return;
        _browserDimension.Width = width;
        _browserDimension.Height = height;
        DimensionsChanged?.Invoke(_browserDimension);
    }

}

public class BrowserDimension
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

}

Add this javascript functions

```
<script>
        window.registerViewportChangeCallback = (dotnetHelper) => {
            window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('OnResize', window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            });
            window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('OnResize', window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            });
        }

        window.getDimensions = function () {
            return {
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            };
        };
    </script>
```

Here is how you can use it in a component

```
@code {
    public BrowserDimension dimensions;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        dimensions = await BrowserService.GetDimensions();
        await BrowserService.RegisterResizeListener();
        BrowserService.DimensionsChanged += UpdateDimensions;
    }

    private void UpdateDimensions(BrowserDimension newDimensions)
    {
        dimensions = newDimensions;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Unsubscribe from the event when the component is disposed
        BrowserService.DimensionsChanged -= UpdateDimensions;
    }
}
```

I'm not completly satisified with the solution since I have to first get the dimension in the OnInitilizedAsync and then use events to set the updated dimensions. I've tried making a solution where I only use events but have not figured out a way to make it work, please let me know if you find a way.